# How to add NSLayoutConstraint in IB but not add until later?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm developing an app with a relatively complex navigation system which relies heavily on auto layout.

Instead of programmatically defining constraints, I'm wanting to design them in Interface Builder but not add them to the view until a certain event is triggered by the user.

If I uncheck "Installed" for the constraint, I'm able to add it later on most devices by using the addConstraint: method, but on other devices the constraint is NULL. Is it possible to ensure that the reference to this constraint which isn't installed initially is kept on all devices and iOS versions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the NSLayoutConstraint class doesn't have enable/disable flag the only option (I think) you have is the following:

- Define all constraints in IB
- Create **strong** bind properties to all constraints
- In `viewDidLoad` remove the constraints you don't need from the view (`[self.view removeConstraints: @[self.constraint1, self.constraint2]]`)
- When event is triggered by user - add them back and force re-layout